# Referencing controller methods in my index page in a scaffold-ed rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

rails newbie here. I've started making a value based to-do list.

So far I've scaffolded my app like this:

```
dir> rails --database=mysql test1
dir> cd test1
test> ruby script/generate scaffold list item:string done:boolean value:int
[Changed default value of done to false in the migration file]
test> rake db:migrate
```

All is working well, and I've changed my index view to do what I want except a easier way to flag a task as done. Instead of using the link_to helper to go to an edit page every time I want to change the value of a task's done boolean from false to true I want to be able to press a button that would change the value of this boolean. How would I do this? I've looked around both the net and my Agile Web Development with Rails and found nothing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit:
This is how the edit view changes the values in the table:

```
<h1>Editing list</h1>

<%= error_messages_for :list %>

<% form_for(@list) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <b>Item</b><br />
    <%= f.text_field :item %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Done</b><br />
    <%= f.check_box :done %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </p>
<% end %>


<%= link_to 'Show', @list %>
<%= link_to 'Back', lists_path %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog post](http://www.russellquinn.com/2008/02/03/customing-form-controls-in-rails/) has roughly what you are looking for.  Just change the images so they are the buttons you want.